# Rectangle has area $3/4$ and diagonal $5/4$. What are the lengths of the sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

**Problem:** What is the dimension of a rectangle that has a diagonal that measures $5/4$ units and has an area of $3/4$ units squared?

**My work:** Using trial and error I have come up with the dimensions $1$ and $3/4$, but I don't know how to show the solution to how I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w$ and $h$ be the width and height. Then we have:

$wh = \dfrac34$
$w^2+h^2=\left(\dfrac54\right)^2 = \dfrac{25}{16}$

The first equation gives $w = \dfrac{3}{4h}$. Subsitute this in the second equation and you get a quadratic equation in $h^2$, which you can solve.

Comment: Yep,  works for me too! Thanks! Thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Let your rectangle have sides of length $a$ and $b$. Thus, $ab=3/4$. Also, the diagonal is $5/4$ units in length. Thus, $a^2+b^2=(5/4)^2$. Hence, you end up needing to solve
$$
16b^4-25b^2+9=0.
$$
If you solve this, then you will see that you got *one* of the possible solutions, but there are really two (when considering the distinction between length and width to be arbitrary). However, this other possible solution involves $a$ or $b$ being *negative* which is clearly impossible (unless you would like for your rectangle to have negative length and width). Thus, your solution is correct.

Comment: Wow,  thanks for the help. Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

Define two sides of the rectangle as $ x $ and $ y $. Since the rectangle's diagonal is $ \frac{5}{4} $ units, using the Pythagorean theorem:

$$ x^{2} + y^{2} = \Big(\frac{5}{4}\Big)^{2} $$ or $$ \mathrm(1)\hspace{10mm} x^{2} + y^{2} = \frac{25}{16} $$

You're also given the rectangle's area to be $ \frac{3}{4} $ units squared. Since the area of the rectangle is the product of its sides:

$$ \mathrm(2)\hspace{10mm} xy = \frac{3}{4} $$

To solve this system of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, begin solving for $ x $ in equation $(2)$ by dividing a $y$ to each side:

$$ x = \frac{3}{4y} $$

Substituting the value of $ x $ shown above to equation $(1)$:

$$ \Big(\frac{3}{4y}\Big)^{2} + y^{2} = \frac{25}{16} $$ or $$ \frac{9}{16y^{2}} + y^{2} = \frac{25}{16} $$

Subtract a $y^2$ to each side:

$$ \frac{9}{16y^{2}} = \frac{25}{16} - y^{2} $$

Multiply a $16y^{2}$ to each side:

$$ 9 = \Big(\frac{25}{16} - y^{2}\Big)(16y^{2}) $$

Distribute the above equation's right side:

$$ 9 = 25y^{2} - 16y^{4} $$

To make the above equation resemble a quadratic, subtract $9$ to each side:

$$ 0 = 25y^{2} - 16y^{4} - 9 $$

Now let $ w = y^{2}$. Rearranging the right side terms in descending order:

$$ 0 = -16w^{2} + 25w - 9 $$ or $$ -16w^{2} + 25w - 9 = 0 $$

The above equation is of the form $ax^{2} + bx + c = 0$, so use the quadratic formula, $$ \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a} $$ to solve for $ w $, where $a = -16$, $b = 25$, and $c = -9$. Here:

$$ w = \frac{-25 \pm \sqrt{25^{2} - 4(-16)(-9)}}{2(-16)} = \frac{-25 \pm \sqrt{625 - 576}}{-32} = \frac{-25 \pm \sqrt{49}}{-32} = \frac{-25 \pm 7}{-32} $$ The solutions of $ w $ are $ w = \frac{-25 - 7}{-32} = \frac{-32}{-32} = 1 $ and $ w = \frac{-25 + 7}{-32} = \frac{-18}{-32} = 9/16 $

Since $ w = y^{2} $ from the substitution, hence $ y^2 = 1 $ or $ y^2 = 9/16 $. This rectangle problem is a real-life scenario, and thus the lengths of $ x $ and $ y $ must be positive ($ x > 0 $ and $ y > 0 $). Solving for $ y $ by taking the square root to each side:

$$ y = 1 $$ or $$ y = 3/4 $$

If $ y = 1 $, then substituting into equation $(1)$ and solving for $ x $:

$$ x^{2} + 1 = \frac{25}{16} $$ or $$ x^{2} + \frac{16}{16} = \frac{25}{16} $$ or $$ x^{2}  = \frac{9}{16} $$ or $$ x = \frac{3}{4} $$

If $ y = 3/4 $, then substituting into equation $(1)$ and solving for $ x $:

$$ x^{2} + \Big(\frac{3}{4}\Big)^{2} = \frac{25}{16} $$ or $$ x^{2} + \frac{9}{16} = \frac{25}{16} $$ or $$ x^{2}  = \frac{16}{16} $$ or $$ x^{2} = 1 $$ or $$ x = 1 $$

Thus, the dimensions of the rectangle are $ 1 $ unit by $ 3/4 $ unit.